# What is difference between meetingTypes and supportedServices in webex system

Tags: webex

Request URL -

I tried to get user details from rest API and in that response, i say supportedServices and meetingTypes as below

```
<use:meetingTypes>
  <use:meetingType>220</use:meetingType>
  <use:meetingType>564</use:meetingType>
</use:meetingTypes>

<use:supportedServices>
  <use:meetingCenter>true</use:meetingCenter>
  <use:trainingCenter>true</use:trainingCenter>
  <use:supportCenter>true</use:supportCenter>
  <use:eventCenter>true</use:eventCenter>
  <use:salesCenter>false</use:salesCenter>
</use:supportedServices>
```

what is a difference between these two on webex manages system

Answer (score 1):

meetingTypes control access to specific meetingTypes. You may have multiple  meeting types with different features enabled/disabled. For example, you may not want a certain user to have access to Network Based Recording, so you can explicitly enable or disable a custom session type for the user without NBR enabled.

supportedServices simply controls access to an entire service, such as Meeting Center. You can set any of these to 'false' to disallow a host access to a specific service.